# customized Action bar with layout as background

Tags: android

I have a requirement that I need to display Action bar with home button icon on left side of bar and activity title on middle of the bar with application logo..

So I have designed a layout with these requirements...

I want to set this layout to my  element so that I can set it as a theme..

but I am unable to add my layout to my  element..

Below is the code..

```
 <style name="Theme.MySherlockCustom" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarSize">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">11sp</item>

</style>
```

Please help what can be done to achieve my target.

Comment: Seems like you use Actinbar Sherlock library. Did you check it's demo application??? it's [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/samples/demos).

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code...

  <style name="Theme.Main" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.ActionBar</item>

</style>

<style name="Widget.ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">

    <item name="android:customNavigationLayout">@layout/YOUR LAYOUT</item>
</style>
```